# Unable to load memory from specificed address in eclipse (C++ / CDT)

Tags: c++, eclipse

When I right click on a variable in the debugger, I get the error message above, citing address `x7fffffffe01e` (every time). It also happens if I merely type in the reference.

Am I using this wrong, or is there a bug? I tried to read an eclipse article on using the memory monitor, but I suspect it was written for Java environment and not C++.

I'm Using Elipse 3.8.1 on linux mint 15 (3.11.0-12-generic) on a Samsung NP900X3E Ultrabook

CDT:

> C/C++ GCC Cross Compiler Support 1.1.0.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group    Eclipse CDT
>     C/C++ GNU Toolchain Build Support 8.1.1.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.build.feature.group Eclipse CDT
>     C/C++ GNU Toolchain Debug Support 7.1.1.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.debug.feature.group Eclipse CDT
>     C/C++ Memory View Enhancements    2.2.0.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
>     C/C++ Unit Testing Support    7.0.0.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.testsrunner.feature.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
>     CDT Common GDB Support    7.0.0.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
>     CDT Visualizer Framework  1.0.0.dist  org.eclipse.cdt.visualizer.feature.group    Eclipse CDT

Comment: Did you compile your application on the command line (using `g++ -Wall -g`, and perhaps a `Makefile`)? Did you read the documentation of [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? Did you run `gdb` on the terminal (perhaps as `gdb -tui`)? Eclipse might actually complicate your work....

Comment: I tried command line:

(gdb) p &r
$2 = (short *) 0x7fffffffe09ea
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe09e
0x7fffffffe09e: 0x00000007

And also from within Eclipse - the CDT GDB console:

x &r
0x7fffffffe01e: 0x00000007


But when I try the monitor, it says it can't load the memory address

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, though. That's why I'm asking, I guess :)

And I compiled from within Eclipse:
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
g++  -o "tests"  ./main.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for a pointer with a bad value (e.g. because it is uninitialized) when you dereference it (so the address is not valid in the process' address space). If it not a pointer but a local variable it means that you corrupted your [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). It could also indicate some other [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption).

Try also to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

So there are bugs in your program. Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)